# how to find comma matches containing a specific word?

Tags: regex

In this string :

```
GPN1 VRT Full competence (Tel),GPN1 VRT midle (Tel) ,GPN1 Open Mobile AC GNE (Tel),GPN1 VRT Best competence (Tel)
```

I would like to extract all the content between commas containing the word VRT.

I tried this regular expression : `[\s\w]*VRT.*?(?=,)`.

It works on the first one but I can't repeat it so that it gets me all the others.

Could you, please, help me?

Comment: Your regex is fine; how to solve the rest of the problem depends entirely on which tool you are trying to use for this task. Please [edit] to clarify; see also the [tag:regex] tag guidance which was displayed to you when you selected this tag.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
[^,]*VRT[^,]*
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/P1vy0M/1). If the `VRT` must be matched as a whole word, add word boundaries:

```
[^,]*\bVRT\b[^,]*
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/P1vy0M/2). *Details*:

- `[^,]*` - zero or more non-commas
- `\bVRT\b` - `VRT` enclosed with word boundaries
- `[^,]*` - zero or more non-commas.

Comment: @ChristopheC. and this [does return](https://regex101.com/r/P1vy0M/4) what you expect.

Comment: Sorry, I copied your solution incorrectly, it works perfectly. Thanks a lot